# WPF 自動的に隠れるコントロールを作る時のコンテキストメニューの問題

Tags: wpf

Windows10、VisualStudio2015、.Net4.6、WPF、C# で開発しております。

以下のようにIsMouseOverを利用して自動的に隠れるコントロールを作っているのですが、コンテキストメニューを開くとIsMouseOverがFalseになってしまうようで期待する動作になりません。

コンテキストメニューが開かれているときもコントロールを表示状態にしたいのですが、どのようにしたら良いのでしょうか。

---

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenu.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContextMenu"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="LightGray">

        <!-- MouseOver状態で自動的に表示する -->
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.1"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>

        <TextBox Text="ここでコンテキストメニューを開くと..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10"/>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

別のフォーカス対象が必要になりますが、`IsFocused`を使用した解決方法を思いつたので投稿します。

追記：自動的に隠れる条件に「フォーカスされていない」を加えることを許容する場合の回答になります

```
<Grid>
    <!-- 別のフォーカス用 -->
    <Grid x:Name="other" Focusable="True" Background="#FEEE" MouseDown="other_MouseDown" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"/>

    <!-- 自動的に隠したいパネル -->
    <Grid  x:Name="grid" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >

        <!-- MouseOver状態で自動的に表示する -->
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.1"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tb, Path=IsFocused}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>

        <TextBox x:Name="tb" Text="ここでコンテキストメニューを開くと..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10"/>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

---

```
    private void other_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.other.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: この方法だとコンテキストメニューがキー操作やウィンドウの切替で閉じられた場合にイベントが発生しません

Comment: 自動的に隠れる条件に「フォーカスされていない」を加えた場合の回答である旨を追記しました

Answer (score 1):

`ContextMenu`を自分で指定している場合は`ContextMenu`が表示されている場合(`IsOpen="True"`)のトリガーを追加してやればいいのではないでしょうか。

```
<Grid
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    Background="LightGray">

    <!-- MouseOver状態で自動的に表示する -->
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style
            TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter
                Property="Opacity"
                Value="0.1" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger
                    Property="IsMouseOver"
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Opacity"
                        Value="1" />
                </Trigger>
                <!-- トリガーを追加 -->
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding ElementName=tb, Path=ContextMenu.IsOpen}"
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Opacity"
                        Value="1" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>

    <!-- Nameを設定 -->
    <TextBox
        Name="tb"
        Text="ここでコンテキストメニューを開くと..."
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="10">
        <!-- ContextMenuを設定 -->
        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem
                    Header="a"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
    </TextBox>

</Grid>
```

また`TextBoxBase`などに用意されているWPF標準ポップアップは通常のプロパティやイベントでは判断できないので、

1. `PropertyDescriptor`を使って`IsMouseOver`イベントをハンドルする。
2. `PresentationSource`から対象の`Popup`を探す。

という2個のトリックを使う必要があります。

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // IsMouseOverの変更イベントをハンドルする。
    var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(UIElement.IsMouseOverProperty, typeof(Grid));
    dpd.AddValueChanged(grid, Grid_IsMouseOverChanged);
}

private void Grid_IsMouseOverChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // IsMouseOverがTrueの場合は処理終了
    if (grid.IsMouseOver)
    {
        grid.Opacity = 1;
        return;
    }

    // マウスが実際に乗っているか判定する。
    var mp = Mouse.GetPosition(grid);

    if (0 < mp.X && mp.X < grid.ActualWidth
        && 0 < mp.Y && mp.Y < grid.ActualHeight)
    {
        // 内部の要素に対して表示されているPopupを探す
        var popup = PresentationSource.CurrentSources
                    .OfType<HwndSource>()
                    .Select(_ => ((_.RootVisual as FrameworkElement)?.Parent as Popup))
                    .FirstOrDefault(_ => _?.IsOpen == true && _.PlacementTarget == tb);

        // TODO:PlacementTargetに対する条件を任意の要素に対応できるよう変える

        if (popup != null)
        {
            // PopupのClosedイベントを処理する
            popup.Closed += Popup_Closed;
            return;
        }
    }
    grid.Opacity = 0.1;
}

private void Popup_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grid.Opacity = grid.IsMouseOver ? 1 : 0.1;
    ((Popup)sender).Closed -= Popup_Closed;
}
```

Comment: 自分で用意したContextMenuではうまくいきましたが、TextBoxコントロール標準のコンテキストメニューを使用する場合はうまくいかないようです

Comment: @nee 意図を勘違いしていましたので、標準`ContextMenu`の場合を追加しました

Comment: 右クリック連打でコンテキストメニューを連続で開いた場合や、文字を選択してからコンテキストメニューを開いて`その他(O)...`で変換候補ポップアップが表示される場合等にうまくいかないようです。開かれているコンテキストメニューのコントロールを取得する方法は勉強になります。